# Python running exe file inside GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe

Using py2exe, I was able to successful make many individual python files into many individual .exe files, and run the .exe program. I then place all of these .exe files into a python GUI. The GUI would display all of my exe files in a Combobox.

From the Combobox, the user would select which single .exe file they want to open, and then the .exe file would run.

I'm able to get my GUI to run as a python program. When the user selects the .exe file, the .exe file runs, but one I convert my GUI into a .exe program it will no longer run the .exe file the user selected.

Here is my code for the GUI application that places all of my individual .exe files in to a Combobox.

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class Parking_Gui(Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        """Sets up the window and widgets"""
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.geometry("325x125")
        self.master.title("MSU PARKING APP")
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.grid(sticky = N)

        # Label for the parking lots
        self._LotLabel = Label(self, text = "MSU Parking")
        self._LotLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        # Combo Box for individual exe program added to Combobox
        self._ComboValue = StringVar()
        self._LotCombo = Combobox(self, textvariable=self._ComboValue,
                                  state='readonly', height = '5',
                                  justify = 'center')

        self._LotCombo['values'] = 'BURG.exe' //the exe app
        self._LotCombo.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        # Button to open word file
        self._button = Button(self, text = "Open", command = self._openFile)
        self._button.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

    def _openFile(self):
        """Event handler for the button. Will open the .exe file
           associated with selected item"""

        User_Selected_exe_file = self._LotCombo.get()
        os.startfile(User_Selected_exe_file)

def main():
    Parking_Gui().mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: What does "no longer run" mean? Are you getting errors? Does the program crash?

Comment: The error message i am given is that "Burg.py" can not  import 'matt'. I'm not sure why it can no longer import matt. Everything was running perfect, but once I converted the GUI into a .exe file, it can no longer import the module matt

Comment: have you considered the case that maybe you forgot to include "matt.py" when you created your .exe?

Comment: I've thought the same same thing, so I added 'import matt' into my setup.py file, and ran py2exe. Still the same problem